# r - dplyr: weighted sum of group returning multiple values error

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, I have subwatersheds with % forest cover, and I want to find the % forest cover for the larger watershed comprised of these subwatersheds.

The data look like this:

```
df
          W_ID    sub_area    w_area   sub_forest 
             1        500      3045       15.5     
             1        650      3045       0     
             1        700      3045       32.4    
             1        645      3045       50.1    
             1        550      3045       16.9   
             2        480      2720       0.9   
             2        560      2720       18.5      
             2        760      2720       80.5 
             2        820      2720       18.6
```

I tried to use dplyr

```
df %>%
   group_by(W_ID)%>%
   summarise(forest=(sum(sub_area*sub_forest)/w_area))
```

but it returns this error code

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : expecting a single value
```

A similar approach using mutate doesn't return an error, but it returns *n* values of forest cover for *n* subwatersheds, whereas I want only *m* unique values of forest cover for *m* watershed IDs.

```
df %>%
  group_by(W_ID)%>%
  mutate(forest=(sum(sub_area*sub_forest)/w_area))
```

How do I properly use summarise to get % forest cover for each W_ID?

Comment: Can't you just move `/w_area` inside of the `sum(...)` expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that `w_area` is a vector with length greater than 1. Doesn't matter that it has the same value for the whole group, `2 / c(1, 1, 1)` is `2 2 2`.

You can move the division inside the sum as in the comment and other answer. This works because division distributes across a sum.

Another option - a more general option - is to use a function of `w_area` that returns a single value, say `first(w_area)` or `w_area[1]`. A *safe* way to do that is to use `unique()`, which will return a single element if there is only one distinct value, but will throw this error if you have different `w_area` values within the same group, perhaps alerting  you to a bad assumption or an earlier bug.

Answer (score 2):

We need to change the brackets of `sum` to do the `sum` of proportion instead of `sum` of the products divided by 'w_area'

```
df %>% 
    group_by(W_ID) %>% 
    summarise(forest = sum(sub_area * sub_forest/w_area))
#    W_ID   forest
#  <int>    <dbl>
#1     1 23.65829
#2     2 32.06765
```